# % of Column Total SSRS Matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to display an SSRS row subgroup value as a percentage of its column total grouped by the row subgroup.

My goal:

[image: 1]

Notice how the values in red display as a percentage of the value in the RowSubGroupTotal, whereas the RowSubGroupTotal displays as percentage of the ColumnGroup total.

What I currently have:

[image]

The red values display as a percentage of the ColumnGroup total (just like the RowSubGroupTotals do).

How do I change those red values to rollup to 100% - their values as a percentage of the RowSubGroupTotal?

My matrix:

[image]

Raw data: [RawData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RBgp.png)

I want the red values to be a percentage of the RowSubGroupTotal (3/4 = 75%, 1/4 = 25%). I want the RowSubGroupTotal to be a percentage of the column subtotal (4/25 = 16%, 9/25 = 36%).

Comment: please provide sample data related to requested output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the field is called `Amount`, your outer row group is called `BlueRowGroup` and your dataset is called 'DataSet1` then the expression for the red rows would be something like

```
=SUM(Fields!Amount.Value) / SUM(Fields!Amount.Value, "BlueRowGroup")
```

and the blue rows would be

```
=SUM(Fields!Amount.Value) / SUM(Fields!Amount.Value, "DataSet1")
```

The first part of the expression does not state the scope as this will be the scope of the textbox the expression resides in. The second part states the scope of the total amount we want to divide by, so for the red rows, we want to divide the amount by the total amount from the next group up (`BlueRowGoup`). For the blue rows we want the amount to be divided by the total for the entire dataset so we use the dataset name as the scope.

Here is a working exmaple....

I created some data to mirror your sample data, just changed the names to avoid confusing fields with groups/scopes.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(RowGroup varchar(10), SubGroup varchar(10), Amount int)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('Alpha', 'Red', 2),
('Alpha', 'Red', 1),
('Alpha', 'Green', 0),
('Alpha', 'Blue', 1),
('Bravo', 'Red', 1),
('Bravo', 'Green', 0),
('Bravo', 'Blue', 4),
('Bravo', 'Blue', 4),
('Charlie', 'Red', 0),
('Charlie', 'Green', 4),
('Charlie', 'Blue', 2),
('Charlie', 'Blue', 6)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I added a simple tablix showing both the actual underlying numbers and the %'s, which looks like this.

[image]

I set the expression as earlier in this answer.

This gives the following result...

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. hadn't finished the question yet was playing with images :) updated with more info.

Comment: you need to use the row group, not the column group as the scope and for the blue rows, as I said in my answer, use the whole dataset as the scope.

Comment: Thanks. The blue rows are already doing what I want them to do. They roll up to to the column subtotal (16 + 32 + 48 = 100). I want the red rows to roll up to 100 as a percentage of the RowSubGroup total. So the raw values in those cells as a percentage the values behind 16, 32, and 48. Will get the raw data in here as well.

Comment: Have yo tried the first expression? That should do what you want.

Comment: Yes I've tried scopes for the three groups I have (RowGroup, RowSubGroup, and ColumnGroup) and it's not working.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show a working exmaple. The expression I gave you should give you exactly what you want. If not then there must be something fundament that is different from your exmaple

Comment: Thanks yes I know what you're referring to but my data does not want to work even when I put that RowGroup in for scope. There's some detail I'm missing in my example I believe as the images I provided are an abstract of the actual data i'm working on. Will keep playing with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Figured out my issue which ended up being slightly tangential to the ask here. But you helped!

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use ReportItems expressions to create the ratios.
In any case you dont need the original values you can use hidden columns to make the calculations

Your expression could be like

**vs rowgroup1 total (yellow)**

```
=Sum(Fields!val.Value) / ReportItems!Textbox9.Value
```

**vs rowgroup2 total (orange)**

```
=Sum(Fields!val.Value) / ReportItems!Textbox12.Value
```

For the ReportItem reference use the related cell name

[image]